# Fill ion-content with div

Tags: ionic4

I have a ion content that I fill with a div. This works great when the screen size is larger than the div content. If it is smaller, then it assigns the height of the view, and when you scroll down it doesn't fill the whole content. It can be seen in the following example:

[image]

This is basically the html:

```
<ion-header>
  <div id="headerTab" [class]="loginStyle">
  <ul style="justify-content: center; display: flex;" class="tabs z-depth-1">
    <li class="tab col"><a (click)="setTabIndex(0)" class="active" href="#enter">ENTRAR</a></li>
    <li class="tab col"><a (click)="setTabIndex(1)" href="#signup">REGISTRO</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id="background" [class]="loginStyle" style="margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; text-align: center;">

        <div class="valign-wrapper center-align tabs-content" *ngIf="loginTabVisible" [@showAnimation] (@showAnimation.done)="reloadTabs()">

          <form *ngIf="loginVisible" [@showAnimation] (@showAnimation.done)="reloadLoginPage()">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="correo" type="email" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="userEmail" name="userEmail">
                <label for="correo">Email</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="pass1" type="password" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="userPassword" name="userPassword">
                <label for="pass1">Contraseña</label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <a class="btn bg_color_s" (click)="login()">Continuar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <a (click)="setLoginPageIndex(1)" class="">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>

          <form *ngIf="resetPasswordVisible" [@showAnimation] (@showAnimation.done)="reloadLoginPage()">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12" style="color: #fff">
                <p> Por favor, introduzca su correo. Le enviaremos un email con insrucciones para restablecer su contraseña </p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="correo" type="email" class="validate" [(ngModel)]="userEmail" name="userEmail">
                <label for="correo">Email</label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <a class="btn bg_color_s" (click)="login()">Recuperar contraseña</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <a (click)="setLoginPageIndex(0)" class="">Volver al inicio de sesión</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>

        </div>

        <div class="center-align tabs-content" *ngIf="registerTabVisible" [@showAnimation] (@showAnimation.done)="reloadTabs()">

          <form *ngIf="registerVisible" [@showAnimation] (@showAnimation.done)="reloadRegisterPage()">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input name="newUser.firstName" [(ngModel)]="newUser.firstName" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="first_name">Nombres</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input name="newUser.lastName" [(ngModel)]="newUser.lastName" id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="last_name">Apellidos</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input name="newUser.birthday" [(ngModel)]="newUser.birthday" id="birthday" type="text" class="validate datepicker">
                <label for="birthday">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input name="newUser.email" [(ngModel)]="newUser.email" id="correor" type="email" class="validate">
                <label for="correor">Email</label>
              </div>

              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input name="password" [(ngModel)]="newUser.password" id="passr1" type="password" class="validate">
                <label for="passr1">Contraseña</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input name="passwordCheck" [(ngModel)]="passwordCheck" id="passr2" type="password" class="validate">
                <label for="passr2">Repita contraseña</label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <a (click)="signUp()" class="btn bg_color_s">continuar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <a (click)="toggleRegisterPro()" class="">{{ toggleRegisterProMessage }}</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>

          <form *ngIf="proTypeVisible" [@showAnimation] (@showAnimation.done)="reloadRegisterPage()">

            <div class="row">
              <div style="width:90%;margin:auto">
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="group1" type="radio" />
                    <span>Jugador Profesional</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="group1" type="radio" />
                    <span>Campo de Golf/Pitch and putt</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="group1" type="radio" />
                    <span>Tienda de Golf</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="group1" type="radio" />
                    <span>Otros servicios relacionados</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <a href="login_pro_2.php" class="btn bg_color_s">continuar</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <a (click)="toggleRegisterPro()" class="">{{ toggleRegisterProMessage }}</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>

        </div>

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

The problem can be summed up to:

```
<ion-content>
<div style="height:100%; background-color: red">
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the content overflows the div. We can make use of `overflow: overlay` to solve the issue.

Simply add in the container div this property:

```
<ion-content>
<div style="height:100%; background-color: red; overflow: overlay">
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
<p> This is some content </p>
</div>
</ion-content>
```